# Volume of solid of revolution ($\cos(x)$)

Tags: integration, trigonometry, volume, solid-of-revolution

Compute the volume of the solid of revolution that results from revolving $f(x)=\cos(x)$ between $x=-\pi/2$ and $x=\pi/2$ around $y=-1$. I know how to do so around the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis, however, I am not sure what to do in this case.

Comment: If you shift the coordinate axis down, you can think of the rotation surounding the line y=0 and f(x)=cos(x)+1. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the graph, you can see that it is the same volume as revolving $ f(x) = cos(x) + 1$ around the x-axis. You just translate the whole thing up with 1.